# How to style a link assigned with class?

Tags: css

I have a link to whom I have given a class now I want to style that link.

```
<a href="demolink.com" class="link1">Click</a>
```

`.link1` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It should be working https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/358/

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    .link1 {
        // CSS goes here
    }
</style>
```